# OpenVPN not routing on DD-WRT

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, router

The problem is pretty easy to explain, basically I have 2 tunnels open on the server. 1 tunnel goes to our main office so I can manage the company servers. Another tunnel goes to our branch office where I keep my personal server I use for testing. At my house I have a Cisco E3000 router with DD-WRT installed on it with OpenVPN.

The problem I having the tunnel to the main office works fine, but the tunnel going to the branch office is NOT routing correctly and I am having a hard time figuring out why.

I looked at the routing table on the DD-WRT to see whats going where, but it "looks" to be in order but I am not really sure.

The thing that really throws me is when I run `traceroute` from DD-WRT each tunnel gives me a different response.

When I traceroute something on the main office network (e.x. 192.168.0.5) it returns this.

`traceroute to 192.168.0.5 (192.168.0.5), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets

 1  172.16.0.1 (172.16.0.1)  23.840 ms  28.757 ms  25.812 ms

 2  192.168.0.5 (192.168.0.5)  27.548 ms  26.601 ms  23.459 ms`


When I traceroute something on the branch office network (e.x. 10.0.0.15) it returns this.

`traceroute to 10.0.0.15 (10.0.0.15), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets

 1  10.0.0.15 (10.0.0.15)  16.376 ms  17.826 ms  13.257 ms`

Something is definately wrong because the `10.0.0.0` network is NOT the network I am on. DD-WRT's subnet is (192.168.1.0/24). So I am not sure what is going on.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you haven't sorted this out yet, can you also post the OpenVPN server config? I just bumped into this question today.

Comment: `ip route ls table all` will also be helpful to diagnose the problem